# pexpect child.before and child.after is empty

Tags: python, pexpect

```
>>> ssh_stuff
['yes/no', 'Password:', 'password', 'Are you sure you want to continue connecting']
>>> prompt
['$', '#']
>>> child = pexpect.spawn('ssh kumarshubham@localhost')
>>> child.expect(ssh_stuff)
1
>>> child.sendline(getpass.getpass())
Password: 
11
>>> child.expect(prompt)
0
>>> child.sendline('ls -l')
6
>>> child.expect(prompt)
0
>>> print child.before, child.after
```

can one tell me why my child.before and after is empty, it should return directory listing.

Answer (score 0):

The `expect` method takes a pattern or a list of patterns. These patterns are treated as regular expressions. This is maybe not so clear from the documentation, but if you look into the code of `pexpect`, then you can see that it is the case.

The prompt variable is given as

```
prompt = ['$', '#']
```

The `$` is a special character in regular expression, which will match according to python regex documentation:

> '$' Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches before a newline.

We can see that it is the one being matched in the console output:

```
>>> child.expect(prompt)
0
```

To interpret the `$` sign as a literal it must be preceded by a backslash.

```
prompt = ['\$', '#']
```