# python output of pexpect

Tags: python, pexpect

```
 def connect(user,host,keyfile,release):
    global Stop
    global Fails
    try:
            perm_denied = 'Permission denied'
            ssh_newkey = 'Are you sure you want to continue'
            conn_closed = 'Connection closed by remote host'
            opt = ' -o PasswordAuthentication=no'
            connStr= 'ssh ' + user + '@' + host + ' -i ' +keyfile + opt
            child = pexpect.spawn(connStr)
           ret=child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT,perm_denied,ssh_newkey,conn_closed,'$','#'])
            print(child.before)
            if ret== 2:
                    print('[[-] Adding Host to !/.ssh/known_hosts')
                    child.sendline('yes')
            elif ret ==3:
                    print('[-] Connection Closed by Remote Host')
                    Fails += 1
            elif ret > 3:
                    print('[+] Success.' + str(keyfile)+ ' ' + str(ret))
                    Stop = True
    finally:
            if release:
                    connection_lock.release()**
```

Please check the python code I have above.

when I execute:

python3 brutekey-ssh.py -H 127.0.0.1  -u root -d dsa/1024/

```
[-] Testing keyfile dsa/1024/a31b082ec6434d65c2adf76862b9aca7-30343
[-] Testing keyfile dsa/1024/fb80119b7615bbeb96cb7d2f55b7533d-10375
b''
[+] Success.dsa/1024/1f09490e311786ec22ff32715ca106e9-1279 4
[*] Exiting:Key Found
b''
[+] Success.dsa/1024/b23696eee5b31ed916002d3ec2ddb5f6-18108 4
b''
[+] Success.dsa/1024/a31b082ec6434d65c2adf76862b9aca7-30343 4
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Even it get a permission denied, it still matches `ret > 3`, why?
2. How to check the exact output of `child.expect`
3. Do I need to use `.*\$` instead of `$`? does `$` only match the exact `$` in the output?

Comment: What string did you give in perm_denied?

Comment: Add the the `print` value of `child.before` just after this statement `ret = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT,perm_denied,ssh_newkey,conn_closed,'$','#'])` So we can tell the exact cause of the problem.

Comment: Errr what are you trying to do? You usually need `expect` if you have to pass a password/username to a blocking process that expects those inputs on the command line. You are ssh-ing with a key, though, so you don't need to do that...

Comment: Futhermore, typically a return code of `0` from a process means success on Unix based systems. Return codes greater than 3 can mean just about anything...but not success.

Comment: expect doesn't return process codes. It returns index

Comment: I edite my origibal post: add print(child.before) , print the ret vaiable . I also paste the whole fun here ,so u can see variable 'perm_denied'. But when I execute it ,even the child.before is '', ret is 4...............

Comment: it seems this link has right answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056626/pexpect-child-before-and-child-after-is-empty

Answer (score 0):

**1:Even it get a permission denied, it still match ret>3 why?**
ans: Probably because the output of the `perm_denied` case contained one of the bash characters('#', '$'), print the value of `child.before`or take manual steps to be sure what's happening before automating. It should return 0 in case it didn't match anything and caused a TIMEOUT. And it returns 0 instead of raising an exception because you added `pexpect.TIMEOUT` to the list.

**2: How to check the exact output of child.expect?**
ans: `child.expect` returns the index(int) of the item in the list you passed to it. So in your case you passed `[pexpect.TIMEOUT,perm_denied,ssh_newkey,conn_closed,'$','#']`, `.expect` will return the index of whatever that was matched **first from left to right** by the backend regex. The exact value of it is in your `ret` variable.

**3: do I need to use .*\$ instead of $? does '$' only match the exact $ in output?**
ans: Yes it is enough to match the bash prompt. The only case where they might break is when something from your child prints out a `#` character from some function.

`pexpect` has good [documentation](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html), Read the examples here and it should be plenty.

Comment: I edite my origibal post: add print(child.before) and print the ret vaiable. Even the child.before is '', ret is 4...............

Comment: I want to check whether the ssh login is successful

Comment: the exact prompt from my manual test is: ssh root@127.0.0.1 -i  dsa/1024/1f09490e311786ec22ff32715ca106e9-1279 -o PasswordAuthentication=no
Permission denied (publickey,password).